# ASP.NET MVC C# How To Separate Navigation Bar Links?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project in C# ASP.NET Core with MVC. Currently I have added so far 4 categories to which users can upload files, they categories being displayed in a navigation bar. Problem is, all of the navigation bar items (links) do not even have spacings between them. Can anyone help me out with a sample code, please, on how to have a serious space or even vertical line between them? I am new and not very good at cs.html.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Choose between the skill categories:</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            
            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Beginner", "Index", "Home", new { id = "incepator" })</li>


            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Intermediate", "Index", "Home", new { id = "intermediar" })</li>

            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Advanced", "Index", "Home", new { id = "admin" })</li>
            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Master", "Index", "Home", new { id = "master" })</li>
            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Show All", "Index", "Home", new { id = "" })</li>




        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the navigation bar to help visualise the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible way is to add CSS (example follows) and parameter ", new { @class = "navbar-li" }" to your @Html.ActionLink function. Parameter adds class "navbar-li" to li tags. CSS styles the content.

Modified sample:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .navbar-li {
          font-family:'Open Sans'
          font-size: 15px;  
          padding: 15px 15px;
        }
        
        ul.navbar-nav {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        ul.navbar-nav li {
          border-right: 1px solid #000;
        }

        ul.navbar-nav li:last-of-type {
          border-right: none;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Beginner", "Index", "Home", new { id = "incepator" }, new { @class = "navbar-li" })</li>
        <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Intermediate", "Index", "Home", new { id = "intermediar" }, new { @class = "navbar-li" })</li>
        <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Advanced", "Index", "Home", new { id = "admin" }, new { @class = "navbar-li" })</li>
        <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Master", "Index", "Home", new { id = "master" }, new { @class = "navbar-li" })</li>
        <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Show All", "Index", "Home", new { id = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-li" })</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by serious space, you mean visually on the web page, you do that via the CSS. Or using a 
 html tag if you want them vertically spaced, but Id advise against the latter.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.